# Download NDVI data in Excel for every country in the world from 1982 to 2016

Tags: data, ndvi

I am a research intern and I need to get the average monthly NDVI for all countries in the world in an Excel file.

How can I do this?

I have already tried with NASA EarthData, Copernicus, Google Earth Engine, GIMMS, NEO... and many others. For most of them, I can get the data to retrieve the map and the pixels but I don't have any software to analyze and export this data in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already nice community tutorial for this if you want to perform in Earth Engine. You can just change the dates/regions/reducers for your own purpose.
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/spatiotemporal-image-statistics
You can adapt this based on your need.

Further comments:
But, I am not sure how country level mean NDVI would be that helpful as each country is likely to have the massive diversity. It would be more helpful if you select specific region/area of the country that relates with specific ecological phenomenon to make the NDVI more relatable.

Comment: This tutorial worked well. However, I can't download the data for some countries such as Canada, USA, Iran, Estonia, Ivory Coast and a few others. I got the following error :Encoded string is too large, found more than 16777216 bytes.
Would you have any advice to acquire those data ?

Comment: Yes, that happens when area is extremely large. We need to decrease the size of study area.